# Magento: Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_P<' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491

Tags: magento

I am using magento. In magento, i tried to display products on home page for that i followed

http://vimeo.com/1070986 and i also tried

http://www.blog.magentosupport.net/2011/02/make-a-category-page-the-homepage-in-magento/

But it isn't showing the products that i added. Instead, in home page there appears an error

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_P<' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: 'Mage_Catalog_Block_P<' should be:
'Mage_Catalog_Block_P'

Answer (score 1):

To display products on home page from category, follow this step.

Create new category then add the products which you would like to display on front page to this category.

Add below line in CMS home page

**{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="9" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}**

Here "9" defined your category Id.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your class name on your layout. It must be wrong of naming of block on layout. I mean on your cms home page on admin.